# Fluid Viewport/Render Inconsistency

Tags: rendering, 3d-view, fluid-simulation

The fluid in my render looks significantly different to the fluid in the rendered view in my viewport as you can see from the pictures. If you can't see the pictures, the fluid in the rendered view looks like it's flowing into a significantly thinner bottle than the one that it's actually flowing into. It does not flow in and fill the entire bottle to the edges like it does in the viewport rendered view.

[image: Rendered]

This is the rendered version, and below is the viewport rendered view.

[image: Viewport]

[image: Viewport with Settings]

[image: Viewport Solid]

I have no idea what’s causing this or how to fix it and I don’t know where else to ask besides here.
I’ve tried varying levels of surface thickness, using the planar tickbox, re-baking with different resolutions, but none of my changes have had any effect.

Is there anyone here who might know what the problem is and/or how to fix it?

Comment: Are you using cycles or eevee? I can't see it anywhere in your question or images

Comment: Check if all scales (domain, emitter, meshes, ...) are applied (Ctrl A): they all should have a scale of 1,1,1. Check also if there is a modifier which has a different setting between view and render (eye and camera icons on the modifier).

Comment: I'm using Cycles, and I've applied the scales to all the necessary objects but it made no difference.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, it turns out that it was the Subsurf making the fluid domain smaller at render.